# Splitting a string that has delimiters into 3 variables

Tags: c++

I created this code to split a string into 3 different strings str_days, str_column and str_time. I was wondering if there was a better way to split it into 3 variables. Possibly using just 1 if statement?

```
string::size_type pos = combinedString.find(';');
if (combinedString.npos != pos) {
    combined2 = combinedString.substr(pos + 1);
    str_days = combinedString.substr(0, pos);
}
string::size_type pos2 = combined2.find(';');
if (combined2.npos != pos2) {
    str_column = combined2.substr(pos2 + 1);
    str_time = combined2.substr(0, pos2);
}
```

Comment: have you tried strtok?

Comment: You can migrate your logic into a single function.

Comment: @CIsForCookies I looked at it but wasn't sure how to use it. There are a ton of examples of just printing it our right away but none on how to assign each variable you have split.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yeah, I'm wondering how you would do that as I can't figured out how to do it with .find

Comment: @johncliffe I'm not sure how `find` adds to the complexity of making this a function. Can you share your attempt at writing this function?

Comment: @CIsForCookies:  The `strtok` function only applies to C-Style strings (character arrays that have a nul terminating character).  The `strtok` actually modifies the character array.  The OP is using `std::string`.

Comment: I recommend reviewing `std::stringstream` and treating the string as you would an input file, e.g. using `operator>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), specifying `';'` as the line delimiter, eg:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string combinedString = ...;
std::string str_days, str_time, str_column;

std::istringstream iss(combinedString);
std::getline(iss, str_days, ';');
std::getline(iss, str_time, ';');
std::getline(iss, str_column);
```

Comment: Gonna accept this and point out for anybody in the future in order to do this you must include:

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

Answer (score 1):

If it suits you, you can wrap the gory details behind a variadic function:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Iterator, typename Delimiter>
bool split_into(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Delimiter, std::string & first)
{
    first.assign(begin, end);
    return true;
}

template <typename Iterator, typename Delimiter, typename... Strings>
bool split_into(Iterator begin, Iterator end, Delimiter d, std::string & first, Strings & ... strings)
{
    auto i = std::find(begin, end, d);

    first.assign(begin, i);

    if (i != end) {
        return split_into(++i, end, d, strings...);
    }

    return sizeof...(Strings) == 0;
}
```

Then invoke like so:

```
std::string combinedString("foo;bar;baz;widget");
std::string a, b, c;

split_into(combinedString.begin(), combinedString.end(), ';', a, b, c);

// a == "foo"
// b == "bar"
// c == "baz;widget"
```

`split_into()` will return false if there were not enough delimiters encountered to populate all of the passed arguments.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7078e1b350e8e760)